# Form in pure JavaScript to jsx issue

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redirect

I have a pure JavaScript/HTML snippet:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script language="Javascript">
        function OnLoadEvent() {
            document .123123.submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body OnLoad="OnLoadEvent();">
    <form name="123123" action="http://www.123.com" method="POST">
        <textarea style="display: none" name="PaReq"> 
    </textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="ew" value="1">Hlleo
        <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="testtest">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

By Clicking the submit button the button and the form-data will be sent to a page on the server called http://www.123.com and I will be redirect to this page with the html response. I'm trying to write the exact same function in react. The only exception is that the submit should be done when the component is rendered. I must NOTclick the submit button for the form submission and redirection to the page.

So I wrote:

```
class Form extends React.Component {

    state = {
        ew: 1,
        md: 'testtest',
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onSubmit({
            termUrl: this.state.termUrl,
            md: this.state.md,
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.onSubmit({
            termUrl: this.state.termUrl,
            md: this.state.md,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return ( <
            form name = "123123"
            onSubmit = {
                this.handleSubmit
            } >
            <
            h3 > Form < /h3> <
            textarea style = {
                {
                    display: 'none'
                }
            }
            name = "PaReq" > < /textarea> <
            span > < /span> <
            input type = "hidden"
            name = "TermUrl"
            value = {
                this.state.termUrl
            }
            /> <
            input type = "hidden"
            name = "MD"
            value = {
                this.state.md
            }
            /> < /
            form >
        );
    }

}


class App extends React.Component {

    submit = (values) => {
        console.log('Submitting', values);
        const url = 'http://www.123.com';
        fetch(url, {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: values,
            })
            .then((resp) => {
                console.log('Got response', resp);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error('Got error', err);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return ( <
            div >
            <
            h2 > React App < /h2> <
            Form onSubmit = {
                this.submit
            }
            /> < /
            div >
        );
    }
}    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

The submission of the form when the component is rendered is successful but i'm not redirect to the page **http://www.123.com**  as when clicking on the submit button so I cannot render the html response from the server. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: Why use fetch if you are redirecting anyway???

Comment: Maybe this is the error. What should i use..sorry for the foolish question but i'm entry level

Comment: This is a react class so document.123...submit() returns error because document is undefined. Tha'ts where i'm stuck :(

Comment: So just add it at the end of the page before the </body>

Comment: Ok i'll try it ;) thank you

Comment: I have not body tag in my react classes

Comment: After the </form> then

Comment: It is not working

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Could you please copy/paste my code with where i should put this?

Comment: Sorry - I am not a react specialist